# PHP: How to activate class "active" in pagination, If $_GET['page']==$pagenumber

Tags: php, pagination

This is my pagination code:

```
<?php 
   while($pagenumber != $totalpages) 
     { 
        echo"<a href='?page=" . ++$pagenumber. "' >" . $pagenumber. "</a>     ";  
     }
 ?>
```

The above code will look like this in normal html:

```
<a href="?page=1">1</a>
<a href="?page=2">2</a>
```

I want to add `class="active"` with this condition

```
If ($_GET['page'] == " . $pagenumber . ")
echo "class="active" ";
```

I do not know, how to insert if statement inside echo command.

`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you are:

```
<?php 
while ($pagenumber != $totalpages) {
    ++$pagenumber;
    $class = ($_GET['page'] == $pagenumber) ? 'active' : '';
    echo "<a href='?page={$pagenumber}' class='{$class}'>{$pagenumber}</a>";  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this might help:

```
if ($_GET['page'] == $pagenumber) echo "<a href='?page=$pagenumber' class='active'>$pagenumber</a>";
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try:

```
<?php 
while($pagenumber != $totalpages) { 
    $active = ($_GET['page'] == $pagenumber) ? ' class="active"' : '' ;
    echo '<a href="?page='.++$pagenumber.'"'.$active.'>'.$pagenumber.'</a>';  
}
?>
```

You will have a very clean HTML code without the class attribute empty on the non-active elements.